# How to pass as much arguments to a function as there is variables starting with "string"?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Example :

```
VARIABLE1="/foo/bar"
VARIABLE2="/some/other/path"
# etc you don't know how many variables there is, maybe 3 maybe 30.
# Then :
randomfunction $VARIABLE1 $VARIABLE2 #... <- How do I replace this to something that would include every variable starting with name "VARIABLE"
```

**EDIT**

As there is some misunderstanding, let me put it differently :

How do I make :

```
VAR1="foo"
VAR2="bar"
VAR3="job"
```

being outputed as :

`"foo bar job"` without knowing the number of VAR, maybe there is also VAR4, maybe VAR5 etc.

Comment: Why are you hardcoding variables that you just want to pass on?  And what is the function actually for?

Comment: Just to make editing easier, because I may have a lot of variables. The function is actually "rsync" but I didn't state it so there is no misunderstanding about the purpose of the question (not about rsync).

Comment: @Wildcard Not sure to deserve a "-1"... I made an edit to be clearer.

Comment: Indeed.  It's actually an interesting question.  Probably not something that should be your first resort, but it could have some interesting applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the `set` command without any arguments, it will output all the variables and functions that where set for the session, with that in mind is just a matter of filtering the variables and then filtering the "string" you want from those variables, assign that to an array and then pass the array to the function.

```
ALL_VARIABLES=( $(set | grep -Ea '^VARIABLE.*=' | cut -d = -f 2) )
randomfunction "${ALL_VARIABLES[@]}"
```

basically you will get all the output from `set` and `grep` for any line that starts with `VARIABLE` followed by any characters and an equal sign, then you will pass it to `cut` to separate name and value, and assign all the values to the `ALL_VARIABLES` array, which then will be expanded and passed as arguments to `randomfunction`

Comment: That was it ! Glad to see the question was understandable after all. Thanks very much for the well explained answer : )

Comment: Actually using this script made me realize this solution works except when one of the variables has wildcard in it such as `VAR1="/path/to/*.txt"`. In this case `randomfunction $VAR1` works, but `randomfunction ${ALL_VARIABLES[@]}` doesnt, because it seems to be outputed with quotes that make the wildcard interpreted as string. Do you have any easy suggestion for fixing this ?

Comment: Try making `VAR1` an array, like this: `VAR1=("/path/to/*.txt")`, sorry I can't explain why, I don't know exactly how globing is made in this cases, but this works for me.

Comment: I tried this solution. `Echo`-ing `$VAR1` gives a list of .txt files (with full path) separated by spaces, however `echo`-ing `${ALL_VARIABLES[@]}` gives `([0]`... So it doesn't seem to work to me... what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use array and pass the array to function.

```
#!/bin/bash

Variable=(/tmp /tmp/a.txt /tmp/b.txt)

function Test(){
Values=("$@")
echo "${Values[0]}"
echo "${Values[1]}"
echo "${Values[2]}"
}


echo "${Variable[0]}"
echo "${Variable[1]}"
echo "${Variable[2]}"
echo "${Variable[@]}"

#Call the Test function and pass the array
Test "${Variable[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually the whole point of my question is about how to do when you don't know the number of variable coming ?

Comment: As I commented below the post, I would like to pass as many VARIABLES as there is, so I can do `rsync all-the-hardcoded-variables-which-are-actually-source-paths /destination/path`